# Google Sheets: Sorting data into sub sheets from a main ledger

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to create a main order book where I record my purchases of different types of assets. Let's assume the order book contains the following columns:

1. Date
2. Asset Name
3. Asset Type (Asset A, Asset B, Asset C)
4. Quantity
5. Price/Unit

Now I wish to segregate these assets into various sub sheets based on their asset type. Let's say if it were Asset A then Asset Name, Quantity populates automatically into Asset A's sub sheet whenever I enter the data in the order book. All the asset pages have **Asset Name** and **Quantity** in the first 2 columns. I found a code from the stock portfolio video which helps in automatically populating the Stock page but it is limited to only one asset which is Stock but I wish to have the above-mentioned details in the respective asset pages and no asset page duplicates orders.

Sample Code for Stocks Portfolio Example:

```
function MyPortfolio(tickers, values) {
  var total = []
  var sums = {}

  for(i=0; i<tickers.length; i++){
    
    var t = tickers[i].toString()

    if(t !="Cash"){

      if(t in sums){
        sums[t] += Number(values[i])
      }
      else{
        sums[t] = Number(values[i])
      }
    }
  }
  for(var ticker in sums){
    if(sums[ticker]>0){
      total.push([ticker,sums[ticker]])
    }
  }
  return total
}
```

My first approach was to inherit this code into three separate functions, example below:

```
function asset_a_logger(tickers,type, values) {
  var total = []
  var sums = {}
  for(i=0; i<type.length; i++){
    
    var t = type[i].toString()
    var x = type[i].toString()
    if(t !="Gold"){
      if(t!="Crypto"){
      var x = tickers[i].toString()  
        if(x in sums){
          sums[x] += Number(values[i])
        }
        else{
          sums[x] = Number(values[i])
        }
    }
  }
  for(var ticker in sums){
    if(sums[ticker]>0){
      total.push([ticker,sums[ticker]])
    }
  }
  return total
}
}
```

I also tried the following codes but they didn't work, please explain why. In one I tried conditioning over a list but the orders came in all of the asset pages.

```
function asset_a_logger(tickers,type, values) {
  var total = []
  var sums = {}
  for(i=0; i<type.length; i++){
    
    var t = type[i].toString()

    if(t !="Asset B"||"Asset C"){
     
      var x = tickers[i].toString()  
        if(x in sums){
          sums[x] += Number(values[i])
        }
        else{
          sums[x] = Number(values[i])
        }
    }
  }
  for(var ticker in sums){
    if(sums[ticker]>0){
      total.push([ticker,sums[ticker]])
    }
  }
  return total
}
```

```
function asset_a_logger(tickers,type, values) {
  var total = []
  var sums = {}
  var prop = ["Asset C", "Asset B"]
  for(i=0; i<type.length; i++){
    
    var t = type[i].toString()

    if(!(t in prop)){
     
      var x = tickers[i].toString()  
        if(x in sums){
          sums[x] += Number(values[i])
        }
        else{
          sums[x] = Number(values[i])
        }
    }
  }
  for(var ticker in sums){
    if(sums[ticker]>0){
      total.push([ticker,sums[ticker]])
    }
  }
  return total
}
```

I know there's some looping constraint going wrong but I have no prior experience in JavaScript. It is all too easy in Python and I hoped to have a clean and responsive portfolio manager in google sheets.

**Thank You for your patience!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `QUERY` function will do this for you.

It would typically be like this in cell A1 of the relevant asset sheet:

`=query(OrderBookSheet!A:E,"select B,D where C contains 'Asset A' order by B",1)`

The `QUERY` can be altered to order by different columns eg. `order by A desc,B` and other items in the `where` clause to filter it further if needed, like by date, eg., `where C contains 'Asset A' and A >= date '2021-05-01'` .

The date in the above example can be a value in a cell (eg. Cell N1) by replacing `'2021-05-01'` with `'"&text(N1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'`.

If Asset A contained items of the same name (in col B), then you could group them with something like this:

`=query(OrderBookSheet!A:E,"select B,sum(D) where C contains 'Asset A' group by B label sum(D) 'Quantity' ",1)`.

The components of the query (clauses) need to go in a specific order:

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#language-clauses

Comment: Dear Aresvik you just solved the most pressing issue in my life. You have made all of this so easy. I was busy understanding functions and iterating them without knowing what to do when all this while the most self-aware function "QUERY" was the solution. You have made all those minutes worth now. Thanks a ton man!

Comment: Happy to help. `QUERY` is really awesome and worth learning. I didn't mention, but if you want the match to be case-insensitive, then use `where lower(C) contains 'asset a'`. You can also replace `'asset a'` with a cell value by referring to `'"&lower(X1)&"'` where X1 is the cell. If the cell value contains an apostrophe, then use `"""&lower(X1)&"""`  (replace each outer single quote with 2 double quotes)

Comment: Okay! I'll deep down more into queries they are much alike SQL's so wouldn't be much of a problem. But once again thank a lot!

Comment: Hey Aresvik? I've incurred a problem. Whenever I add a new purchase in the order book the data mismatches in the asset page. Let's say I bought a new MF named D(Keeping in view that A and B have already been bought and there are columns such as Curr NAV, Invested Amount, Quantities P&L etc.). So when the buy order is feeded into the orderbook the name of the fund and its quantity have unique positions in the order book but the other columns as mentioned earlier now are in the new row. In a way name of one fund is referring to the properties of other.

Comment: I wish to add a complete new row with each new record so that this mismatch could be avoided.

Comment: Can you share a copy of a sample sheet, read-only. I can take a look later today for you. `ARRAYFORMULA` and `VLOOKUP` work well with `QUERY` so I'm sure we can find a solution.

Comment: Here you go. Though i've made some temporary arrangements would love to know what is easier. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ViVQ6XXCS6AOrRLlmJd0bQDLVjiaCInGk0uAiKLgIL8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: OK, thanks. What in the sheet do you need to alter? What's not working? What outcome do you need?

Comment: It might be easier if you open a new question? I've taken a look at your sheet and `QUERY` can be used on an asset page to work out everything, as long as you put `CURR_PRICE` on the Ledger in col I (not sure how it updates). Typical `QUERY` would be: `=query(query(LEDGER!A:I,"select C,sum(F),avg(G),I,sum(H),sum(F)*I where D contains 'Crypto' group by C,I label C 'PAIR', sum(F) 'QUANTITY', avg(G) 'AVG PRICE', sum(H) 'INVESTMENT', sum(F)*I 'CURR VALUE' ",1),"select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col6-Col5,(Col6-Col5)/Col5 label Col6-Col5 'P/L', (Col6-Col5)/Col5 'P/L %' ",1)`

Comment: I think this will work best when I've one function to find the current price of the asset. In my case for crypto I have an API, for MF I have an IMPORTDATA function and for gold it is manual. I've included ISIN code for MF in the main ledger and everything works fine. I'll hold on to this query for future references. Thank you once again! You are helping me grow a lot!!!!